# issue with customizing Kernel 2.6.35

Tags: kernel

I am trying to set the following values : **CONFIG_STANDALONE=n
CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_DSDT=y
CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_DSDT_FILE="DSDT.hex",**

I am in the middle of customizing a kernel, I have issues with the command `apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname-r)`. Also, I tried `apt-get build-dep linux` which gives same output like the file or folder doesn't exist. Is there any alternate option to fix the issue?

Regards,

Karthik.

Comment: You mention some kernel configuration options, but then you state that the problem is with the command `apt-get build-dep ...`  What's the issue that you are having exactly?  Can you post a sample error message or transcript of the command that is failing?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)